# New to android, can't switch between intents

Tags: android

I have a button, and when it is clicked I'd like to load a new view.

I am using this main activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void buttonPressed(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, SwitchedActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

And then I'd like to load this other activity

```
public class SwitchedActivity extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);
}
}
```

So what should happen, is I click the button in activity_main.xml, and then it loads the layout from activity_two.xml.

The problem is, when I click the button, the app just crashes.

I get this logcat stack trace:

```
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232): Process: com.johncorser.myapp, PID: 1232
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     ... 11 more
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.johncorser.myapp/com.johncorser.myapp.SwitchedActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:839)
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at com.johncorser.myapp.MainActivity.buttonPressed(MainActivity.java:40)
08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     ... 14 more
```

Fair warning, I'm probably doing something VERY stupid, I'm new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty certain that you did not declare the second activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

You should have in your manifest:

```
<application ... >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        ... >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SwitchedActivity"
        ... >
    </activity>

    ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies in your logcat:

> 08-18 11:36:09.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1232): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.johncorser.myapp/com.johncorser.myapp.SwitchedActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

So add it to your manifest like so

```
<activity
        android:name="SwitchedActivity"
        android:label="Switched">
</activity>
```

Whenever you add a new activity, be sure to add it to your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Add the second activity to your manifest file. The log you posted clearly states the problem.

Add the following to your manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".SwitchedActivity"/>
```

Please make sure you read the logcats next time or google the logcat message.